# How do I notify views owned by a custom adapter that they're going away?

Tags: android, listview

In my current project I've extended BaseAdapter (using the tutorial EfficientAdapter as a guide) to handle a couple of different custom cell types, each with its own custom view. Some of those cell types start asynchronous operations (playing and recording media, for example). I'd like to pause them when the activity they belong to goes away (which several other cell types can cause to happen). Is there any way to notify a particular view that the ListActivity to which it "belongs" is going away?

My first thought was to iterate over the views in the `onPause()` method of the activity:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        CustomCellHolder holder = adapter./* Some magic goes here */;
        holder.handlePause();
    }
}
```

but I can't figure out how to iterate over the views owned by the list adapter. Is there a way to do that, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

If it's relevant, my getView method looks something like this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CustomCellHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        /* Create and cache a new view */
        holder = newHolderForItem(someArrayListOfObjects.get(position));

        holder.setItem(feature.attributes.get(position));
        holder.setActivity(MyListActivity.this);

        convertView = holder.getView();
    } else {
        /* Load a cached view */
        holder = (CustomCellHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.setItem(feature.attributes.get(position));
        holder.setActivity(MyListActivity.this);
    }

    holder.doSomeStuff();
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, you're better off not having the view be responsible for doing any logic (playing/recording media).  Refactor the code so that it's the Activity's responsibility which will make it trivial to pause the media in onPause.

Comment: While that's certainly tempting, I will have a dozen or so different types of view (and corresponding holder/controller) in this activity, and possibly several instances of each type. I chafe at the prospect of placing all the logic in the (very long) activity instead of delegating the responsibility out to per-cell controllers.

Comment: In that case, have you tried iterating through the children of your listview?  Also, what adapter are you using?

Comment: Indeed, iterating through the children of the listview will do what I want. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept if and upvote it. My only concern with that is whether listviews can have children (say, a header) that aren't the cells themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the children of your listview to get the custom views you want.  You can check the View.getTag if they have a holder (and is thus a cell).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an ArrayAdapter, just use the "getItem(position)" method. Like:

CustomCellHolder holder = adapter.getItem(i);

Comment: Is there an equivalent if I'm not using an array adapter?

Comment: Sorry, every Adapter has this method! Just use it. Iterating through the children of your ListView is more expensive than that.